# Function Warnings in C

Tags: c, function, warnings

Hello guys i have threefunctions for which i get 4 warnings...!!

The first one is this

```
void evaluatearxikos(void)
{
    int mem;
    int i;
    double x[NVARS+1];

    FILE *controlpointsarxika;

    controlpointsarxika = fopen("controlpointsarxika.txt","r");
    remove("save.txt");


    for(mem = 0; mem < POPSIZE; mem++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < NVARS; i++)
        {
            x[i+1] = population[mem].gene[i];


        }
        rbsplinearxiki();

        XfoilCall();

        population[mem].fitness = FileRead();
        remove("save.txt");


    }

       fclose(controlpointsarxika);
}
```

For this one the compiler warns me tha variable x is set but not used...!! But actually i am using the variable x...!!!

The second function is this one...

```
void elitist(void)
{
    int i;
    double best,worst;
    int best_mem,worst_mem;

    best = population[0].fitness;
    worst = population[0].fitness;

    for(i = 0; i < POPSIZE - 1; i++)
    {
        if(population[i].fitness > population[i+1].fitness)
        {
            if(population[i].fitness >= best)
            {
                best = population[i].fitness;
                best_mem = i;
            }

            if(population[i+1].fitness <= worst)
            {
                worst = population[i+1].fitness;
                worst_mem = i+1;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            if(population[i].fitness <= worst)
            {
                worst = population[i].fitness;
                worst_mem = i;
            }

            if(population[i+1].fitness >= best)
            {
                best = population[i+1].fitness;
                best_mem = i+1;
            }
        }
    }

    if(best >= population[POPSIZE].fitness)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < NVARS; i++)
        {
            population[POPSIZE].gene[i] = population[best_mem].gene[i];


        }

        population[POPSIZE].fitness = population[best_mem].fitness;
    }

    else
    {
        for(i = 0; i < NVARS; i++)
        {
            population[worst_mem].gene[i] = population[POPSIZE].gene[i];

        }

        population[worst_mem].fitness = population[POPSIZE].fitness;
    }
}
```

For this one i get two warnings that the variables worst_mem and best_mem may be used uninitialized in this function..!! But i initialize values to both of them..!!

And the third function is this...

```
void crossover(void)
{
    int mem,one;
    int first = 0;
    double x;

    for(mem =0; mem < POPSIZE; mem++)
    {
        x = rand()%1000/1000;

        if(x < PXOVER)
        {
            first++;

            if(first%2 == 0)
            {
                random_Xover(one,mem);
            }

            else
            {
                one = mem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For which i get that the variable one may be used unitialized..!! But it is initialized..!

Can you please tell me what is wrong with these functions...??

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please note, that additional exclamation marks do not improve the quality of your question.

Comment: Perhaps you should paste the actual compiler warnings as well, that would probably make it easier for people to help you interpret what they mean.

Comment: You initialize your variables inside conditions. The compiler cannot prove the condition ever holds (can you?) Just initialize them outside of any condition or loop to be safe. As for the unused variable warning, I don't see where you are using it either.

Answer (score 4):

In your first function, you set (assign) x, but you never read it, hence you are not using it... you're only wasting CPU cycles by writing to it. (Note also that because you index it as `i+1` you write beyond the space you've allocated for it).

In the second function, your initializations to those variables are in conditional blocks. You can see that (perhaps? I didn't verify) in all conditions they are initialized but your compiler isn't that smart.

In your third function, it does appear that `one` could be refered to without having first been initialized.

Comment: Same question here, I might be blind but I don't see the third function (although it's not pretty) could be using the value unitialized?

Answer (score 1):

First: You set `x` but do *not* use it. It's a local variable that gets set but it's dropped as soon as the function returns.

Second: There might be values that makes it so that your `best_mem/worst_mem` never gets set in your `if/else`, but you are using them later on. If they haven't been set, they contain garbage if not initialized.

Third: While it shouldn't happen that you try to use an uninitialized variable in your code, it still looks weird and compiler doesn't see that it won't happen first time.

When you get compiler warnings, treat is as you are doing something wrong or rather *not recommended* and that it could be done in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `x` variable is only used on the left hand side (i.e. assigned a value). You are not using that value on the right hand side or pass it to a function.
2. It may be possible to get to the end of the loop `for(i = 0; i < POPSIZE - 1; i++)` without those variables given a value. Why not set them in the declaration.
3. The call to `random_Xover(one,mem);` could be called when `one` is not set. Change the line `int mem,one;` to `int mem,one = <some value>;`

Comment: Regarding point 3, now I might be blind but I don't see the third option as possible in practice in this case.

Comment: @Jite - The compiler cannot prove the case that `one` is always defined. As far as it knows `rand` is just a function like any other. So it can imagine that `if(x < PXOVER)` evaluates to true.

Comment: I understand why the compiler can't see it... I said though that I can't see how `one` could be used uninitialized though. You say that `random_Xover()` can be called with uninitialized variable `one`, but in pratice it can't if I'm not blind.